# Javascript function is supposed to run after form submission, but does not complete

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML form, I call a Javascript function like so:

```html
<form method="get" onsubmit="dataSubmitted()">
   <input type="text" name="data" id="data_form">
</form>
```

Here's the beginning of my JS function:

```
function dataSubmitted(){

    alert('first');
    let input = document.getElementById('data_form').value;
    alert('second');
    let fs = require('fs');
    alert('third');
```

When I refresh the page, I receive the 'first' and 'second' alerts (this code should not even be running). When I submit something in the form, I get the 'first' and 'second' alerts, and then the page refreshes, after which the 'first' and 'second' alerts appear again. The 'third' alert never shows. Why would this be happening?

Comment: You're submitting a form which is loading a brand new page over top of your existing web page.  So, some of the alerts are fast enough to fire before it gets overwritten but the last one isn't.  You should manually trigger the form submit to occur after all your javascript has executed (using event.preventDefault() and then form.submit())

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the refreshing problems. However, the third alert still does not appear.

Comment: Check for an error maybe that’s halting execution.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the function when the DOM loads, change your html to remove the dataSubmitted invocation like this:

```
<form method="get" onsubmit="dataSubmitted">
   <input type="text" name="data" id="data_form">
</form>
```